# Can't insert into elasticsearch with special characters in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm a little new to elasticsearch and I have a regex and I'm trying to do an insert into elastic search using Java and I have been getting the parsing error I have tried using the / as an escape character and it still fails. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

```
String workflow = "{\"WORKFLOW_ID\":1,\"NAME\":\"Test  Workflow\",\"DESCRIPTION\":\"This workflow will be used for testing\",\"COMPANY_ID\":237,\"SOURCE_ID\":1,\"NODES\":[{\"NODE_ID\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf4\",\"POSITION_X\":0,\"POSITION_Y\":120,\"WORKFLOW_ID\":1,\"NAME\":\"Start Node\",\"TYPE\":\"START_NODE\",\"COMPANY_ID\":237,\"CONNECTIONS_TO\":[{\"FROM\":\"a\",\"TO_NODE\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf5\"}],\"VALUES\":{}},{\"NODE_ID\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf5\",\"POSITION_X\":120,\"POSITION_Y\":240,\"WORKFLOW_ID\":1,\"NAME\":\"Route Node1\",\"TYPE\":\"ROUTE_NODE\",\"COMPANY_ID\":237,\"CONNECTIONS_TO\":[{\"FROM\":\"a\",\"TO_NODE\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf6\"},{\"FROM\":\"b\",\"TO_NODE\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf7\"}],\"VALUES\":{\"VARIABLE\":{\"NAME\":\"Subject\",\"TYPE\":\"String\"},\"CONDITIONS\":[{\"ORDER\":0,\"OPERATOR\":\"Regex\",\"VALUE\":\"\\[#([0-9]+)\\]\",\"TO_NODE\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf6\"},{\"ORDER\":1,\"OPERATOR\":\"\",\"VALUE\":null,\"TO_NODE\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf7\"}]}},{\"NODE_ID\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf6\",\"POSITION_X\":120,\"POSITION_Y\":240,\"WORKFLOW_ID\":1,\"NAME\":\"Work action1\",\"TYPE\":\"WORK_ACTION_NODE\",\"COMPANY_ID\":237,\"CONNECTIONS_TO\":[],\"VALUES\":{\"WORK_ACTION_TYPE\":\"Ticket\",\"STATUS\":\"New\"}},{\"NODE_ID\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf7\",\"POSITION_X\":120,\"POSITION_Y\":240,\"WORKFLOW_ID\":1,\"NAME\":\"Work action2\",\"TYPE\":\"WORK_ACTION_NODE\",\"COMPANY_ID\":237,\"CONNECTIONS_TO\":[],\"VALUES\":{\"WORK_ACTION_TYPE\":\"Ticket\",\"STATUS\":\"Open\"}}]}";
```

This is is the code I'm using to put the data into elasticsearch

```
IndexResponse rescreate = Consumer.client.prepareIndex("workflows", "workflow").setSource(workflow.toString(), XContentType.JSON).get();
```

That's my jsonobject, and this is the error that I get, My regex I'm trying to pass as a value is \[#([0-9]+)\].

> Exception in thread "main" MapperParsingException[failed to parse [NODES.VALUES.CONDITIONS.VALUE]]; nested: IOException[Unrecognized character escape '[' (code 91)
>    at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@670fc0a6; line: 1, column: 823]];
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.parse(FieldMapper.java:302)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:485)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseValue(DocumentParser.java:607)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.innerParseObject(DocumentParser.java:407)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrNested(DocumentParser.java:384)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:482)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:500)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseNonDynamicArray(DocumentParser.java:584)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseArray(DocumentParser.java:542)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.innerParseObject(DocumentParser.java:396)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrNested(DocumentParser.java:384)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:482)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:500)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.innerParseObject(DocumentParser.java:394)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrNested(DocumentParser.java:384)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:482)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:500)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseNonDynamicArray(DocumentParser.java:584)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseArray(DocumentParser.java:542)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.innerParseObject(DocumentParser.java:396)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrNested(DocumentParser.java:384)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.internalParseDocument(DocumentParser.java:93)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:67)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:261)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareIndex(IndexShard.java:708)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.applyIndexOperation(IndexShard.java:686)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.applyIndexOperationOnPrimary(IndexShard.java:667)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.executeIndexRequestOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:548)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.executeIndexRequest(TransportShardBulkAction.java:140)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.executeBulkItemRequest(TransportShardBulkAction.java:236)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:123)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:110)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:72)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryShardReference.perform(TransportReplicationAction.java:1033)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryShardReference.perform(TransportReplicationAction.java:1011)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.ReplicationOperation.execute(ReplicationOperation.java:104)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncPrimaryAction.onResponse(TransportReplicationAction.java:358)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncPrimaryAction.onResponse(TransportReplicationAction.java:298)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$1.onResponse(TransportReplicationAction.java:974)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$1.onResponse(TransportReplicationAction.java:971)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShardOperationPermits.acquire(IndexShardOperationPermits.java:238)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.acquirePrimaryOperationPermit(IndexShard.java:2211)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction.acquirePrimaryShardReference(TransportReplicationAction.java:983)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction.access$500(TransportReplicationAction.java:97)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncPrimaryAction.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:319)
>       at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:294)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:281)
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:66)
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$7.doRun(TransportService.java:652)
>       at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:637)
>       at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might run into this issue. I was converting a json object in String format to String again and hence was running into this issue.

String workflow = "{\"WORKFLOW_ID\":1,\"NAME\":\"Test  Workflow\",\"DESCRIPTION\":\"This workflow will be used for testing\",\"COMPANY_ID\":237,\"SOURCE_ID\":1,\"NODES\":[{\"NODE_ID\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf4\",\"POSITION_X\":0,\"POSITION_Y\":120,\"WORKFLOW_ID\":1,\"NAME\":\"Start Node\",\"TYPE\":\"START_NODE\",\"COMPANY_ID\":237,\"CONNECTIONS_TO\":[{\"FROM\":\"a\",\"TO_NODE\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf5\"}],\"VALUES\":{}},{\"NODE_ID\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf5\",\"POSITION_X\":120,\"POSITION_Y\":240,\"WORKFLOW_ID\":1,\"NAME\":\"Route Node1\",\"TYPE\":\"ROUTE_NODE\",\"COMPANY_ID\":237,\"CONNECTIONS_TO\":[{\"FROM\":\"a\",\"TO_NODE\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf6\"},{\"FROM\":\"b\",\"TO_NODE\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf7\"}],\"VALUES\":{\"VARIABLE\":{\"NAME\":\"Subject\",\"TYPE\":\"String\"},\"CONDITIONS\":[{\"ORDER\":0,\"OPERATOR\":\"Regex\",\"VALUE\":\"\[#([0-9]+)\]\",\"TO_NODE\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf6\"},{\"ORDER\":1,\"OPERATOR\":\"\",\"VALUE\":null,\"TO_NODE\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf7\"}]}},{\"NODE_ID\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf6\",\"POSITION_X\":120,\"POSITION_Y\":240,\"WORKFLOW_ID\":1,\"NAME\":\"Work action1\",\"TYPE\":\"WORK_ACTION_NODE\",\"COMPANY_ID\":237,\"CONNECTIONS_TO\":[],\"VALUES\":{\"WORK_ACTION_TYPE\":\"Ticket\",\"STATUS\":\"New\"}},{\"NODE_ID\":\"node-220ae87b-f74d-22a5-8661-a1d189983bf7\",\"POSITION_X\":120,\"POSITION_Y\":240,\"WORKFLOW_ID\":1,\"NAME\":\"Work action2\",\"TYPE\":\"WORK_ACTION_NODE\",\"COMPANY_ID\":237,\"CONNECTIONS_TO\":[],\"VALUES\":{\"WORK_ACTION_TYPE\":\"Ticket\",\"STATUS\":\"Open\"}}]}";

IndexResponse rescreate = Consumer.client.prepareIndex("workflows", "workflow").setSource(workflow, XContentType.JSON).get();

Doing just workflow will work. workflow.toString() causes problems